# How to apply a different menu styling to the front page?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get a second *menustyling* on a WordPress site that I use *fullpage.js* on.

I have a custom walker and the menu works by *anchorlinks* to slides. I'm trying to figure out how to change the styling on the menu for slides, so the front page has its own.

Site:  http://www.svenssonsbild.se/Svenssonsbild2

Loop:

```
<?php

if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && $locations['slides'] ) {

    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['slides'] );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $pageID = array();

    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if($item->object == 'page')
        $pageID[] = $item->object_id;

    }
    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'page','post__in' => $pageID, 'posts_per_page' =>      
    count($pageID), 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) );

}


while(have_posts() ) : the_post();

?> 


<!--     <div id="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="section"> -->

<div id="pageSlide-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="section" data-anchor="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
```

walker:

```
<?php 
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent      = ($depth)?str_repeat("\t", $depth):'';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes     = empty($item->classes)?array():(array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
        $class_names = ' class="'.esc_attr($class_names).'"';
        $output     .= $indent.'<li id="menu-item-'.$item->ID.'"'.$value.$class_names.'>';
        $attributes  = !empty($item->attr_title)?' title="'.esc_attr($item->attr_title).'"':'';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->target)?' target="'.esc_attr($item->target).'"':'';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn)?' rel="'.esc_attr($item->xfn).'"':'';
        if($item->object == 'page') {
            $varpost = get_post($item->object_id);
            if(is_home()) {
                $attributes .= ' href="#'.$varpost->post_name.'"';
            }
            else {
                $attributes .= ' href="'.home_url().'/#'.$varpost->post_name.'"';
            }
        }
        else 
            $attributes .= !empty($item->url)?' href="'.esc_attr($item->url).'"':'';
        $item_output     = $args->before;
        $item_output    .= '<a'.$attributes.'>';
        $item_output    .= $args->link_before.apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID);
        $item_output    .= $args->link_after;
        $item_output    .= '</a>';
        $item_output    .= $args->after;
        $output         .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to apply a different style for the first section (not slide, slides are  horizontal) you probably want to do it by using the plugin callbacks such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave`.

Something like:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    slidesColor: ['red', 'blue'],
    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        //if it is not in the 1st section, we apply sectionMenu class
        if (index !=1 ) {
            $('.demo').addClass('sectionMenu');
        }

        //otherwise, we remove it
        else{
            $('.demo').removeClass('sectionMenu');
        }
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alvaro! That worked perfect! Last mission is to figure out how to add slides to the loop, then the script is perfect! Thanks again! Edit: I did figure it out, edited my response, sorry.

Comment: Yeah. The `demo` element is suppose to be your menu.

Comment: Very useful, cheers! If you have css3: true enabled then you need to specify the fixed element for this to work (like this http://jsfiddle.net/ut8c6/) confused me for a second!

Answer (score 1):

Use the wordpress body class

on the homepage the body tag will have a class of home like so `<body class="home">`

So on the homepage target the menu like so:

```
.home .your-menu-selector
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but thanks to the script i´m using that doesn't work. It´s #header-section i would like to apply to the slideclasses, but it doesnt work. Thanks though.